# Late evaluation with NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

NHibernate.Linq returns IQueryable giving me late evaluation. Can this also be done with QueryOver?

Update:

I will use it to define lots of queries where only a subset would be used. Therefor Future is not the solution, which would execute them all.

I like the IQueryable (IEnumerable) return type from NHibernate.Linq, that will never execute the query if never used.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, even `QueryOver` is just a set of definitions to be later converted to the SQL statement. So until you are working with a reference to a

```
IQueryOver<Entity, Entity> ab = session.QueryOver<Entity>();
```

and not calling `List<Entity>()` ... the execution is deferred. That's also how you can use the Detached queries [16.1. Structure of a Query](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-querystructure)

```
QueryOver<Cat> query = QueryOver.Of<Cat>()
        .Where(c => c.Name == "Paddy");
```

Another powerful feature is `Future`. This represents a very easy way how to put few queries on the stack, and only when first of them is required... all are executed and passed to DB Server as a *batch*. Read here more:  [NHibernate Futures](http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures)

> They essentially function as a way to defer query execution to a later
>   date, at which point NHibernate will have more information about what
>   the application is supposed to do, and optimize for it accordingly

The biggest difference is that it cannot be returned as `IQueryable` when using `QueryOver`

*EDIT: Extend on a question update*

While `IQueryable<TEntiy>` could be returned only from a `session.Query<TEntity>()` and not when using  *QueryOver*, *ICriteria*, *HQL* ... the same behavior could not be reached when using `QueryOver`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. See extra info in the question.

Comment: Short answer: I don't wanna return a IQueryOver from my repositories. IEnumerable would be good.

Comment: IEnumerable requires call `List()` (just returning more general interface). Still, in this case, when `List()` is called, query is immediately executed

Comment: I know, that is the problem. I just thought that this would be a solved problem in QueryOver. I guess i'll just make a wrapper class that give me late evaluation + IEnumerable

Comment: The power of `IQueryable` is in context of publishing that (mostly via OData) to external consumers. If this is your case, use Linq (session.Query<Entiy>()). To introduce some wrapper, think about publishing `IEnumerable<MyEntity> Find(EntityFilter)`. Then you can gather the *filter* object from upper layers and apply all fitlers in Data layer... selecting only what user requires, including paging